# MS Access 2007 Import Not Working?

Tags: ms-access, import, ms-access-2007, text-files

I just switched from Access 2003 to Access 2007. In the very first "dev" copy (as I call it) pre-split, pre-front end, I need to import some data that are text files. I try to use the ribbon to do this, and after I walk through the steps I get this little pop up box that states

> Microsoft Access has determined this to be a potential security risk. You shouldn't accept....

Then I Click OK to accept (open the file)... and nothing happens...no import, no file.

So I tried making a new table on import, creating a table in access then importing, coverting the data file to xls & web before importing, using a completely different data file. Nothing seems to change the outcome of Access not firing off some type of import event (which I think is supposed to be a wizard or something??)

So does anyone have any ideas what is going on with this?

I would just code the data import but I don't know how (without using the wizard to at least create the specification).

Answer (score 1):

Is the folder where the database resides configured as a Trusted Location?  I know VBA code won't run if it's not.  I wasn't aware those types of restrictions extended to file import from the Ribbon.  However, your error message sounds similar to a Trusted Location issue, so it may be worth checking.

See [Create, remove, or change a trusted location for your files](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-for-your-files-HA010031999.aspx) for detailed instructions on managing Trusted Locations.

Comment: all trusted location are set by group policy, and I cannot modify this on the network. however, this appears to me to be just the wizard form for selected the import type (fixed, delimited, etc) is not firing. the error reference this ACCWIZ\AZWZLIB file, where I am assuming Office store access wizard forms....and this particular form is not firing at this point in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Access was formerly very fussy about extensions and would stop working if, for example, a text file did not have an expected extension. It used to be necessary to modify the registry to get around this. It seems that the problem may still exist.

Comment: I tried creating my own txt file that was stupid simple to test the routine, not really the file. I also tried xls, xml, csv, & html table. they all produce the same results at the exact same place which is this "wizard" form not firing.